# Need help understanding how the machine reads this code

Tags: syntax

```
#  Don't change the code below 
row1 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️","⬜️","⬜️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
#  Don't change the code above 

#Write your code below this row 

horizontal = int(position[0])
vertical = int(position[1])

map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1] = "X" 

#Write your code above this row 

#  Don't change the code below 
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

Question: So I think I understand how this code generally works but I am not sure why the horizontal comes second in the "map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1] = "X"
" line. Wouldn't the horizontal come first since it is the first index [0] and horizontal is being read first (horizontal needs to come first to determine column before we determine the vertical row in this example)?

Edit: I'm asking for help because I genuinely don't know. I've tried looking over it and I've tried researching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

- `map[0]` returns the same object as `row1`, `map[1]` returns the same object as `row2`, and `map[2]` returns the same object as `row3`.
- Rows are (traditionally) visualized as a vertical stack, one on top of each other, the same as one line above the other in the original code.

Thus

```
 a_row = map[vertical - 1]
 a_value = a_row[horizontal - 1]
```

This can be combined as

```
 a_value = map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1]
```

And with assignment of a specific value

```
 map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1] = "X"
```

Comment: This post answers "Wouldn't the horizontal come first since..?" - and no, it would not. If there is a different question, perhaps as part of what should be written to complete the solution, such is not clear.

Comment: @Alex Oh, if "23" is given as a string.. it depends on how that should be read. Is that row,col (2,3) or col,row (3,2)? That is sperate from using `map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1]` (this part is correct, the original variable assignment might not be).

Comment: For an answer of "23" it is supposed to be a vertical row 2 and a horizontal column 3. This is the correct code given by the instructor with the answer being the very bottom box in the middle. It makes sense now looking back on it. Thank you.